# How to download old sdk's in android SDK manager

Tags: android, cordova, android-studio

[image: SDK manager screenshot]

I am not able to check any of these checkboxes

Comment: use android studio

Comment: Please first try to solve the SDK path warning showed below sdk location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing SDK location to C:\dev\sdk solved it, Moved all the contents from old SDK location to this new location.

All the problems where created since i had a space between my windows user name.

Any other location would be fine too for SDK, as long as there are no spaces in the file location path I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Android SDK path error is showing up below the SDK path box. First, try to fix it up. If it still does not help you please go to the

sdk folder -> AndridSDK -> android-sdks -> tools -> android.bat
Double click on that it will open old school type screen like following

[image]